# Jquery .Ajax - How to Pass Data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass a variable via jquery ajax call.   I'm not exactly sure how to do it properly.  I get the lon lat coordinates through another html5 script.

How do i get the coordinates on the other side?  I tried $_GET(lat).

I'm also not sure if i'm able to use the location.coords.latitude in a different < script >.

```
$.ajax({  
    cache: false,
    url: "mobile/nearby.php", 
    dataType: "html",
    data: "lat="+location.coords.latitude+"&lon="+loc.coords.longitude+,
    success: function (data2) {
    $("#nearbysgeo").html(data2);

    }
});
```

These scripts are above the jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {

    $(function() {

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayCoordinates);

      function displayCoordinates(location) {

        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("location"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude), 12);
        map.setUIToDefault();
        var point = new GLatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        map.addOverlay(marker);


      }

    })
  });
</script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function getLocation(){

        if (navigator.geolocation) {

          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

        } else {

            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Your browser doesn't handle the  GeoLocation API. Use Safari, Firefox 4 or Chrome";

        }


    }
    function success(loc){

        console.log(loc);

        strout = "";

        for(l in loc.coords){

            //strout += l +" = " +loc.coords[l] + "<br>";

        }
        strout += '';
        strout += '<center><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='+loc.coords.latitude+','+loc.coords.longitude+'&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:Y%7C'+loc.coords.latitude+','+ loc.coords.longitude+'&zoom=15&size=400x250&sensor=false&center=currentPosition"></center>';

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = strout;

        document.forms['newPostForm'].lat.value = loc.coords.latitude;
        document.forms['newPostForm'].lon.value = loc.coords.longitude;
        document.getElementById("coords").innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById("coords").innerHTML = 'CURRENT: Lat:' + loc.coords.latitude + ' Lon:' + loc.coords.longitude;

    }


    function error(err){

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = err.message;

    }

    function clearBlog() {
            document.getElementById("listview").innerHTML = '';
        }
    </script>
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:

It works if I use this line.  So i guess i can't use loc.coords.latitude this way.

```
data: "&lat=43&lon=-79.3",
```

Well i hacked it for now to get it working.  I filled two hidden form elements on the page with lon and lat values. Then used 'document.forms['newPostForm'].lat.value' to create a line like this.

```
data: "&lat="+document.forms['newPostForm'].lat.value+"&lon="+document.forms['newPostForm'].lon.value,
```

Still would like an actual solution.

Comment: Can you show an example of where `location` (or `loc`) is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code from a project I'm working on.  Very simple.

```
$.post("../postHandler.php", { post_action: "getRecentPosts", limit: "10" }, function(data){
            $("#post-list").html(data);
```

You can switch out .post with .get with no other changes, like so:

```
$.get("../postHandler.php", { post_action: "getRecentPosts", limit: "10" }, function(data){
            $("#post-list").html(data);
```

Data is passed in name value pairs like so.

```
{ post_action: "getRecentPosts", limit: "10" }
```

Rewrite:

```
$.get("mobile/nearby.php", { lat: location.coords.latitude, lon: loc.coords.longitude }, function(data2){
             $("#nearbysgeo").html(data2);
});
```

Comment: I use the coordinates to return html.  Will i be able to do that with .get?

Comment: I tried .get but it doesn't seem to work.  I don't get back the html.  I didn't forget the closing brackets

Comment: Yes, you will be able to return html.

Comment: Are you using FireBug?  Can you tell me what the get request and response are?

Comment: Where in firebug?  I do get this --------------
'location.coords is undefined
[Break On This Error] data: "&lat="+location.coords.latitude+"&lon="+loc.coords.longitude,'

Comment: Under the net panel. Using the example I gave you.

Comment: If you getting absolutely nothing then the script probably isn't executing.  You should at least see the request even if it isn't successful.  For example you can see the requests made by your browser as you submit these comments.

Comment: @vpets let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1269/discussion-between-theoldone-and-vpets)

Answer (score 0):

```
$lat = preg_replace('#[^0-9\.]#', '', $_GET['lat']);
```

You probably can use `location.coords.latitude` if it is defined before.

Comment: i don't know if its defined before.  Do you mean 'var location.coords.latitude' somewhere?  No i don't have that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery.ajax(
                {
                    url     :   'mobile/nearby.php',
                    data    :   { 
                                    'action'     :   'update', 
                                    'newname'    :   'enteredText', 
                                    'oldname'    :   'original_html', 
                                    'userid'     :   '10' 
                                },
                    success :   function(msg){
                                    if(msg == 1)
                                    {
                                           alert('success');
                                    }
                                }
                });
```

this is the proper syntax of `jQuery.Ajax();` function